# Cloud database for Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have some apps in the Play Store and now I am looking to add "cloud data lookup" capability.

- I do not own a server and wish to leverage some existing Cloud services.
- My Android app would perform search operations on various fields of this database and present the data to the user.
- The data that would reside in the cloud is currently in ascii text files. What is the best way to load such data upfront?
  Do I need to store each record as a blob?
- The apps would only perform searches/lookup on this data and NOT write to it.
- I also need to keep updating this data, say at weekly intervals (outside of the apps).
- How do I expose the APIs for fetching data?

I am looking at MBS and Photo Feed examples...so I am guessing I would need some combination of GAE, Google Cloud SQL/Data store..not sure?

Appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction with design thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: Read up on Google Cloud Endpoints  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/